# Show callout when tapping overlay

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an MKMapView with several overlays. Works all just fine, and it's incredible how simple it works. There is, however, one thing I can't get to work. The idea is simple: when a user taps within the area that is covered by an overlay, a callout with some information about that overlay has to come up. The overlays are all `MKPolygon`s, which follow the MKOverlay protocol and therefore the MKAnnotation protocol.

> The MKOverlay protocol conforms to the
>   MKAnnotation protocol. As a result,
>   all overlay objects are also
>   annotation objects and     can be
>   treated as one or both in your code.
>   If you opt to treat an overlay object
>   as both, you are responsible for
>   managing that object in two places. If
>   you want to display both an overlay
>   view and annotation view for it, you
>   must implement both the
>   mapView:viewForOverlay: and
>   mapView:viewForAnnotation: methods in
>   your application delegate. It also
>   means that you must add and remove the
>   object from both the overlays and
>   annotations arrays of your map.

This comes from the Apple docs. I tried something like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

      MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
      aView.canShowCallout = YES;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I've tried using gesture recognizers, but I have no idea how to show a callout other than by using the `canShowCallOut` property...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you have to add the MKOverlays as annotations also

```
 [self.mapView addAnnotations:myOverlays];
```

Then return a MKAnnotationView in (mapView:viewForAnnotation) that's not hidden, either a graphic (tap-able) or zero alpha view. Next, add a UITapGestureRecognizer for each MKOverlayView, make sure it works with the map's gestures (UIGestureRecognizerDelegate implementation for simultaneous recognition). Finally when your gesture recognizer fires do this

```
[self.mapView setSelectedAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myOverlayView.overlay]];
```

I'm not certain that this actually triggers the callOut showing though.
Also make sure your return title and/or subtitle from your overlay object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I set the alpha of the pin to zero, the callout automatically also gets that alpha, so that's not really an option. However, it would be acceptable for me to have the pin show when the user taps the overlay, so that the pin and callout then become visible. I got that working now by using `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` and `mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:`. If you have a suggestion for hiding the pin while showing the callout, it'd be great, but it's not really important.

Comment: When I said 0 alpha view, I meant image/[clear Color] not annotationView.alpha = 0, make a blank png to put on it or make the annotationView a plain clear Color background view of an abstract size.